# How do you organize your Unit Tests in TDD?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I do TDD, and I've been fairly loose in organizing my unit tests. I tend to start with a file representing the next story or chunk of functionality and write all the unit-tests to make that work.

Of course, if I'm introducing a new class, I usually make a separate unit-test module or file for that class, but I don't organize the tests themselves into any higher level structure. The result is I write code fast and I believe my actual program is reasonably well structured, but the unit tests themselves are "messy". Especially, their structure tends to recapitulate the phylogeny of the development process. Sometimes I see myself as trading laziness in the code for laziness in the tests.

How big a problem is this? Who here continually refactors and reorganizes their unit tests to try to improve their overall structure? Any tips for this? What should the overall structure of tests look like.

(Note, that I'm not so much asking the "how many assertions per function" question asked here : [How many unit tests should I write per function/method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110430/how-do-you-organize-unit-tests) I'm talking about the bigger picture.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Divide your tests in 2 sets:

- functional tests
- units tests

Functional tests are per-user story. Unit tests are per-class. The former check that you actually support the story, the latter exercise and document your functionality.

There is one directory (package) for functional tests. Unit tests should be closely bound with functionality they exercise (so they're scattered). You move them around and refactor them as you move & refactor your code around.

Comment: How exactly do you organize the unit tests? I used to write one test per method. But lets say I have a "clear()" and a "isEmpty()" method. Those two are bound to each other. It does not make much sense to write two tests for those because they are actually equivalent: 1. Call clear(), then check if isEmpty() returns true. Up to date I failed to find a organisation strategy that keeps things clear and avoids redudancies. (clear/isEmtpy seems easy but that can get much more difficult)

Answer (score 4):

The less important part is organizing the tests.

I start by putting the tests into a class that relates to the class under test, so com.jeffreyfredrick.Foo has a test com.jeffreyfredrick.FooTest. But if some subset of those classes need a different setup then I'll move them into their own test class. I put my tests into a separate source directory but keep them in the same project.

The more important part is refactoring the tests.

Yes I try and refactor my tests as I go. The goal is to remove duplication while still remaining declarative and easy to read. This is true both within test classes and across test classes. Within a test class I might have a parametrized method for creating a test fake (mock or stub). My test fakes are usually inner classes within a test class but if I find there's need I'll pull them out for reuse across tests. I'll also create a TestUtil class with common methods when it seems appropriate.

I think refactoring yours tests is important to long term success of unit testing on large projects. Have you ever heard people complaining about how their tests are too brittle or preventing them from change?  You don't want to be in a position where changing the behavior of a class means making dozens or even hundreds of changes to your tests.  And just like with code, you achieve this through refactoring and keeping the tests clean.

Tests **are** code.

Answer (score 3):

I write a unit test class for each class in the application, and keep the test classes organized in the same package structure as the classes under test.

Inside each test class I don't really have much organizational structure.  Each one only has a handful of methods for each public method in the class under test, so I've never had any problem finding what I'm looking for.

Comment: How do you keep the tests organized in the same package structure as the classes under test? I find that I cannot keep up with the refactoring of the classes under test if I try to do this.

Comment: @PeterAjtai My IDE (Eclipse) partly takes care of this for me.  I have a root source folder and a separate root test folder.  Each of those has the same package folders within.  When I right-click a class in Eclipse and select the menu option to create a new JUnit test class, I just select the test folder as the root location, and the rest of the package directory structure is copied automatically.  If methods get split off into a new class during refactoring, I create a new test class in the same way, but move & edit the old test methods manually.

Answer (score 3):

For every class in the software, I maintain a unit test class. The unit test classes follow the same package hierarchy as the classes which are tested.

I keep my unit test code in a separate project. Some people also prefer to keep their test code in the same project under a separate source directory called 'test'. You could follow whatever feels comfortable to you.

Answer (score 0):

I try to look at the unit tests as a project on their own. As with any project the organisation should follow some internal logic. It does not however have to be specific or  formally defined - anything you're comfortable with is OK as long as it keeps your project well-organised and clean.

So for the unit tests I usually either follow the main project code structure or (sometimes when the situation calls of it) focus on the functional areas instead.

Leaving them in one heap is as you might imagine messy and difficult to maintain