# QUnit : One test per method with multiple assertions or multiple tests per method?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

I've decided to embark on TDD for my next javascript project and I'm using QUnit for the unit testing. I am completely new to unit testing, having never done it in any language. Here is an example of one of my modules plus one test for the `find` method that tries to cover all scenarios this method will encounter:

```
module("TextSwapper", {
    setup: function() { 
        this.str = 'When you first start off trying to solve a problem, the first solutions you come up with are very complex, and most people stop there. But if you keep going, and live with the problem and peel more layers of the onion off, you can often times arrive at some very elegant and simple solutions.';

        this.ts = new TextSwapper();
        ok(this.ts, 'The TextSwapper was created successfully');

        this.textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
        this.textarea.value = this.str;
        document.body.appendChild(this.textarea);
    },
    teardown: function() {
            document.body.removeChild(this.textarea);
    }
});

test("find()", function() {
    equal(this.ts.find('When'), false, "Check it fails gracefully when no input has been set.");
    this.textarea.focus();
    equal(this.ts.find('When'), true, "Check it finds 'When' if the textarea has focus but no input has been set.");

    this.ts.setInput(this.textarea);
    this.ts.find('When');
    equal(window.getSelection().toString(), 'When', 'The word \'When\' should be highlighted');
    equal(this.ts.found[0][0], 'When', 'The word \'When\' should be in the found array');

    this.ts.find('you');
    equal(window.getSelection().toString(), 'you', 'The word \'you\' should be highlighted');
    equal(this.ts.found[1][0], 'you', 'The word \'you\' should be in the found array');
    equal(this.ts.found.length, 4 ,'Should have found 4 you\'s');

    this.ts.find('bill');
    equal(this.ts.found.length, 0, 'Check that nothing was found for \'bill\'');

    this.ts.find('[a-z]*ee[a-z]*');
    equal(window.getSelection().toString(), 'keep', 'The word \'keep\' should be highlighted');
    equal(this.ts.found[1][0], 'peel', 'The word \'peel\' should be in the found array');
    equal(this.ts.found.length, 2 ,'Should have found 2 for [a-z]*ee[a-z]*');

});
```

My question is am I going about this the right way? Do I have too many assertions in my test? Should my tests be broken down into even smaller tests? I've been reading up on TDD on stackoverflow and I have read a few things now that make me feel like I'm doing this wrong.

Comment: Is this more suited to programmers.stackexchange.com? I suppose I'm not asking about code specifics, it's more of a best practice question. If so could it get migrated? I'm not getting much joy here...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do you organize unit tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110430/how-do-you-organize-unit-tests)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using TDD then you should go for one assertion for each test method.

The following link has a nice explanation of the problems you can run into when testing everything in one method: [Unit testing](http://osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/a-unit-test-should-test-only-one-thing.html) It could more easily introduce hidden bugs in your code.

Comment: Thank you, that link is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a copy of Bob Martin's "Clean Code", he discusses this question in the chapter on unit testing. His opinion is that "one assertion per test" can be a bit awkward (he gives a good example in the book), and he prefers to shoot for "one concept per test" instead. So go ahead and use multiple assertions if you feel that they are closely related and would be annoying to separate.