# Need some advice on how to BDD a simple url parser function

Tags: javascript, tdd, jasmine, bdd

I am practicing BDD using jasmine on a simple function which turns http query string into an object.

```
'a=b&c=d'   ->   {a: 'b', c: 'd'}
```

All i can come up with is:

```
describe('queryParser', function() {
    it('should return query object', function() {
        expect(parseUrl('a=b')).toEqual({
            a: 'b'
        });

        expect(parseUrl('a=b&c=d')).toEqual({
            a: 'b',
            c: 'd'
        });

        expect(parseUrl('&a=b&c=d')).toEqual({
            a: 'b',
            c: 'd'
        });

        expect(parseUrl('a=&c=d')).toEqual({
            a: '',
            c: 'd'
        });

        expect(parseUrl('')).toEqual({});
    });
});
```

But i think there are too many assertion(expect) in one test case. If i am writing tdd, i can divide the assertions into

```
testOneNameValuePair
testMultipleNameValuePairs
testNoNameValuePair
```

But with BDD, could i write sth like `should handle one name value pair case` ? it sounds trivial and weird. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can write `"should parse single name value pair"`, `"should parse multiple value pairs"`, `"should parse empty value"`,etc...It sounds better IMHO

Comment: @Engineer it do sounds better. Seems i can just turn `test bla bla` in TDD into `shoud bla bla` in bdd. But is it too fine grained for bdd ? When doing tdd, some tests can be very small, sometime it's too small to treat as a behavior. Am i over thinking?

Comment: Most books i read about test driven (e.g. Kent Beck's TDD by example) are written in tdd style, but jasmine is the hottest testing framework in javascript, so i always trying to map tdd to bdd. Kind of headache Orz...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do you organize unit tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110430/how-do-you-organize-unit-tests)

Comment: Should, should everywhere should - this is first word that I’m skipping when I read tests results.
`it('returns query object, function() {})`. Look to the accepted answer – is `should` really needed there?

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski Good point.Looked at the [jasmine doc](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html), their sample tests seldom use "should".Maybe lots of bdd tutorials written in this way, so everybody starts to use should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a matter of style (and hence opinion, so it might not belong here...) but I would write something like:

```
it("should be an empty object when the query is empty", function() {
  expect( parseUrl('') ).toEqual( {} );
});

it("should separate names from values with = sign"),  function() {
  expect( parseUrl('a=b') ).toEqual( { a: 'b' } );
});

it("should separate multiple pairs with & sign"),  function() {
  expect( parseUrl('a=b&c=d') ).toEqual( { a: 'b', c: 'd' } );
});

it("should ignore a leading & sign"),  function() {
  expect( parseUrl('&a=b&c=d') ).toEqual( { a: 'b', c: 'd' } );
});

it("should use empty string when a value is missing"),  function() {
  expect( parseUrl('a=') ).toEqual( { a: '' } );
});
```

The thing I'm trying to do here is make sure that my spec name describes not only the conditions, but what I expect the code to do under those conditions as well.

I made only a couple of small changes to the actual assertions you wrote.  I put the empty string case first, because I often use that as my first test.  Also, in the case of a missing value, I left off the second pair.  I think it's extraneous to what is being tested, and leaving it out makes the test easier to read.  These are both matters of style and personal taste, though.

TL;DR:  write spec names that are useful to you and your colleagues.  Nobody else's opinion matters.