# When should I create multiple test functions and should I use pytest fixtures for global variables?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a method that does some filtering of data based on regexes. I have multiple functions that each return a list of regexes, which I combine into one regex string. I then iterate over my list of data, if any of the data matches the combined string, I remove that item from my list of data.

I want to test that when the function runs against a set of data that the filtered items are removed and that the non_filtered items are not removed. I would like to test this for data that matches each of my set of regexes that come from the above functions.

I thought about creating a list of tuples that I could pass to parametrize. Each tuple would include the original list, the list of removed items, and the list of remaining items. Instead of creating this list of tuples for parametrize as a global variable, would it be better to use a fixture for this?

Also, is it better to write separate functions for checking the different behaviors? such as:

```
test that the function removes matched items
test that the function does not remove unmatched items
```

or is it better to write one function and test both things in the same function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many unit tests should I write per function/method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110430/how-many-unit-tests-should-i-write-per-function-method)

Comment: My question is 2 years old. I'm not sure the debate should begin on if it's a duplicate now. And the part of the question that is answered by the other question is only an aside. However, it does answer that aside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I'm a fan of a test function per test case.  If you're testing for different things, I tend to separate those.  That is because when a test fails, I want to know *what functionality broke* rather than just that a big test function has failed.  This often speeds up the cycle time to get things back to working.

This can become cumbersome is there is timely set up involved but I think that is more of a sign that the unit tests should have better isolation, such as using an in-memory database or operating on file-like objects rather than files, etc..

As for the global or not part of the question, I usually just list them anonymously rather than making any variables.  The link at the bottom, however, uses variables.

For reference here is an example that creates 9 tests, using both parametrize for the function and the params argument for a fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[1, 2, 3])
def number(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.mark.parametrize('letter', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
def test_combinations(number, letter):
    pass  # test assertions, etc.
```

If you think it looks more tidy as a variable, do it!  After all, it is just test module...

There are some official examples:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-parametrize

As for what should be a fixture or not, this is a difficult question that is probably widely debated.  I would recommend prototyping different options and comparing them.

Comment: If I have several fixtures in a given test module, and a fixture is only used for a few tests, should that fixture be placed just before the tests that use it, or at the top with all the module level fixtures?

Thanks

Comment: @Mark I would group all fixture at the top of the file.